# Cocoapod: Install pod for internal target (cocoa framework)

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

Hi I want to modularize a project by creating framework and adding it to a project. but when I want to install pods for specific target (I mean frameworks and main target) I will get error.

I had searched for this specific problem and didn't find anything useful.

[Error Image](https://imgur.com/a/tYGtLfe) is Here

[Podfile Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEEY3.jpg) is Here

Error :

> [!] Unable to find a target named `Photo`, did find `testForModule`.

Podfile:

```
# sources
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

# global config
platform :ios, '11.0'
use_frameworks!
workspace 'testForModule'

def networkAndParsingPods
  pod 'Alamofire'
end

def uiPods
  pod 'TextFieldEffects'
end

target 'testForModule' do
  networkAndParsingPods
end

target 'Photo' do
  uiPods
end
```

I'm doing this because of separation concerns, because some module work with specific pod and some module shouldn't access to that.

thanks for any help

Comment: copy the error text and podfile text into the question

Answer (score 1):

`Photo` must be a target in the Xcode project before it can be specified as a target in a Podfile.

Comment: thanks for response its added to the target but I still get same error

Comment: To clarify - `Photo` must be a target - not added to a target.

Comment: I have my main target and I added new one to the main target (workspace) section
is that what you say?? thanks for reply